# Angular 2 / Ionic 2 post request body

Tags: angular, http, post, ionic2

I am trying to send a URL to and API for OCR analysis.

The post request I am sending is the following:

```
post() {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('apikey', 'APIKEY');

  var data = JSON.stringify({url: this.data.url});
  return this.http.post('http://api.ocr.space/parse/image', data, {headers: headers})
  .map(response => response.json());
}
```

The API key registers just fine within the headers but the body is not picked up by the API.

I have tried multiple ways of encoding the body with no success.

Can anybody spot the problem?

The response from the server states no url was sent.

Comment: Where is the documentation of the API? What does it expect?

Comment: @JBNizet It can be found here https://ocr.space/ocrapi it expects url:http://urlexample.com
I should mention I have no problem submitting a request through postman

Comment: As the curl command in the documentation shows, the POST endpoint doesn't expect JSON. It expects the content type to be application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and the body to be `url=http://blablabla`.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you very much! Don't know how I didn't spot that. If you want to post an answer, I will happily accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the curl command in the documentation shows, the POST endpoint doesn't expect JSON. It expects the content type to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and the body to thus be something like `url=http://blablabla`.